# Is there anyway to wait for print window to close in print.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printjs

I have some jquery code using print.js for printing an element and its working fine but I need to know if I can check if the print window is closed and reload the page

```
printJS('print_paper', 'html');
//do stuff after close print window
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a option called `onPrintDialogClose` which is fire after Print dialog close.

```
printJS({
    type: "html",  // Include other option if needed like style , css .....
    onPrintDialogClose: closedWindow 
  });
}

function closedWindow() {
  alert("Window is closed "); // What ever you want to do after window is closed .
}
```

Comment: Thanks @shree. its worked but after close print window not call function.when i move other tab window and come back to that tab window its working.

Comment: `onPrintDialogClose` have some issues. It's not compatible with all browser.  [See git hub issues about this. They are still pending](https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/issues). It's plugin issue not your's.

Answer (score 2):

I tried slebetman's solution in the following link https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/issues/348 and it works fine with me

```
let focuser = setInterval(() => window.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus')), 500);

printJs({

    printable: url,

   onPrintDialogClose: () => {

   clearInterval(focuser);

   // do your thing..

},

onError: () => {

   clearInterval(focuser);

    // do your thing..

  }

});
```